# How do I use multiple pseudo-elements in my selector?

Tags: html, css

I want the first letter of each of my p tags to be a different selection color then the rest of the p tag I tried

```
par::first-letter + par::selection {
  color:pink;
}
```

and

```
par::first-letter::selection {
  color:pink;
}
```

neither work on firefox.

Comment: Please add your markup since `par` is non-standard HTML as a tag/element

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately selector ::selection can only be apply on "simple" selector not construct  one like `first-of-type` or `first-letter`

one not perfect solution i see is to change the first letter of p in js with the letter embeded in a span that can be used to target this first letter

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('p')].forEach(p => {
  p.innerHTML = '<span class="first-letter">'+p.innerHTML[0]+'</span>' + p.innerHTML.substring(1);
});
```

```css
.first-letter::-moz-selection, .first-letter::selection  {
  color:pink;
}

p::-moz-selection, p::selection {
  color: green;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<p class="par">hello</p>
```